# Deprecation warning while setting date in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

How can I make fullCalendar accept different date and time formats?

For example my events have the date in a format like this:

```
02.07.2018 08:55:00
```

For this datetime format i get a warning from moment.js

> "Deprecated warning: value provided is not a recognized ISO format".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deprecation warning is because you might be parsing the date without specifying the format in `moment`. Moment JS internally uses the `new Date()` for which the date should be in [ISO](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) or [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) formats.

The deprecation is because the difference in cross-browser support on parsing the date string.

Chrome parses `new Date("02.07.2018 08:55:00")` to `Wed Feb 07 2018 08:55:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.

Firefox doesn't parses the same and outputs `Invalid Date`.

Verified in Chrome and Firefox in Mac and Linux Fedora.

To overcome this cross-browser overhead, `moment` considers the format you pass as a parameter. Clearly the date you are using is not in those formats.

To suppress the deprecation warning, do any of the following

1. You should mention the date format via the moment object.

`moment("02.07.2018 08:55:00","DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss")`

2. Suppress via `moment.suppressDeprecationWarnings = true;`, before the moment date construction.

The below example adds an event to `July 2, 2018` in the fullCalendar and the date format is given as specified.

```js
$(function() {
  var fc_date_format = "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss";
  var event = {id:1, title:"Logged in to StackOverflow", start:moment("02.07.2018 12:30:45", fc_date_format)}
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      weekends : false
  });
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar("renderEvent", event, true);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Ok, could you give me an example of how to set date format in FullCalendar ?

Comment: @MarkoČepo Updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this problem by setting the eventDataTransform function while initializing fullCalendar. In it i transform the data parameters to a valid format. Partial code with the solution

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    ...

    eventDataTransform: function (event) {
        event.start = moment(event.start, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm');
        event.end = moment(event.end, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm');
        return event;
    }

    ...

});
```